# Dockerfile build : Unable to connect to docker daemon

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to modify the dockerfile of alpine:3.4 to include running git commands and automatically run nginx. Here are the changes I am appending to the default dockerfile.

```
RUN apk update
RUN apk add git
RUN mkdir mygit
RUN cd mygit 
RUN git clone 'some url'

RUN apk add sudo
RUN sudo apk add docker 
RUN sudo docker run --rm --name nginx nginx
```

The git command executes successfully and the `RUN apk add docker` also runs successfully. However, `RUN sudo docker run --rm --name nginx nginx`
fails. 
Here is the log.

`Step 28/31 : RUN sudo apk add docker
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1cdf3005ea4b
Step 29/31 : RUN sudo docker run --rm --name nginx nginx
 ---> Running in 6c8c03b8a97d
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to run docker in docker which is "[not possible](https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind)" by default. Why don't you extend the `nginx` image instead and add git there?

Anyway, this feels like a fool's errand. Instead you should have a building environment in which you would copy application data into a `nginx` container for instance. Don't try to put everything in one container.

For instance look at my example `Dockerfile` which is serving Jekyll based static site:

```
FROM nginx:1.13-alpine

COPY site/         /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY default.conf  /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: I want to be able to start nginx automatically when I build this dockerfile. The other way I found is to use `docker network` to run these two containers on a bridge network using a `docker-compose.yml` and specifying these two services in it. However, I am not sure whether this would allow me to share data between those two containers with a `docker volume`.

Comment: This does not make any sense. Extend the `nginx` container, `nginx` will start automatically. You won't run anything inside the Dockerfile, it's just a blueprint for a image, nothing more nothing less.

Comment: Just as simple as  `FROM nginx:'version'`?

Comment: This way you are extending existing Docker image. Then build your image `docker build -t your_name .` and run it to serve the files `docker run -it -d --rm -p 80:80 your_name`

Comment: This is provides an elegant solution to my problem.

Comment: It's really good to hear. If I did help please mark my answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use one container for one service. 
Use Docker compose for your use case.

For sharing data between two containers, you can always use something like volumes(which is persistent, your host too can use that). This will solve your problem.